# Why including same headers in multiple cpp files and then their compilation works?

Tags: c++, header-files

For example I have 2 cpp files: f1.cpp and f2.cpp, and also a header file: xxx.h.

f1.cpp has the following source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "xxx.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    rect rplace;
    polar pplace;
    cout<<"Enter the x and y values: ";
    while (cin>>rplace.x>>rplace.y)
    {
        pplace=rect_to_polar(rplace);
        show_polar(pplace);
        cout<<"Next two numbers (q to quit): ";
    }
    cout<<"Done.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

f2.cpp source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "xxx.h"

polar rect_to_polar (rect xypos)
{
    using namespace std;
    polar answer;
    answer.distance=sqrt(xypos.x*xypos.x+xypos.y*xypos.y);
    answer.angle=atan2(xypos.y, xypos.x);
    return answer;
} 

void show_polar (polar dapos)
{
    using namespace std;
    const double Rad_to_deg=57.29577951;
    cout<<"distance="<<dapos.distance;
    cout<<", angle= "<<dapos.angle*Rad_to_deg;
    cout<<"degrees\n";
}
```

And xxx.h:

```
struct polar
{
    double distance;
    double angle;
};

struct rect
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

polar rect_to_polar (rect xypos);
void show_polar(polar dapos);
```

I thought that there should be a compiler error because the headers `xxx.h` and `iostream` are included two times: once in f1.cpp and once in f2.cpp. But everything was compiled, so I don't understand how it can work.

Comment: Side note: This is not related to the question (and actually doesn't change anything in this precise example), but of course xxx.h should be protected by “include guards” (or a `#pragma once`).

Comment: @gx_ By "include guards", do you mean `#ifndef` `#endif`?

Comment: @Sunrise [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preprocessor simply reads the header files and puts them into the translation units where the `#include` directive is. If one header file is included in one source file, only that file knows about the declarations in that header file.

You also should know the difference between *declarations* and *definitions*. When you *declare* something, you just tells the compiler that "this thing exists and is of type this-and-that". When you *define* something, you tell the compiler "this is the thing I declared before".

You can have multiple declarations of the same thing. because they only act as meta-data for the compiler, and are not used outside its translation unit. You can however only have one definition of something. That's why you can't define global variables/functions in header files included in multiple source files.

Also, In this answer I talk about "source files", "header files" and "translation units". Header files are the files you `#include`. Source files is the files that does the including (so to speak). And a translation unit is the complete preprocessed source, complete with the source and all included header files, and which is passed on to the actual compiler.

Comment: If header file contain only declarations and I can have multiple declaration of the same, then why I cannot in header file write twice polar struct declaration? However I can double function declaration.

Comment: @Sunrise Some things, like functions, can be declared multiple times in the same translation unit *if they are declared the same*. But things like structures and classes are a little different, because actually *define* the structures, but a structure definition is like a declaration, it doesn't in itself generate any code.

Comment: If I'm properly understood you, structure declaration in reality is structure definition that behaves like declaration. And because it's behaves like declaration I can use it in header files, but because it's also definition that's why I can't write it twice in header file. Then the question appears why structure declaration is actually structure definition?

Comment: @Sunrise A “structure declaration”, often called a “_forward-declaration_”, is just “`struct S;`”. Like a function declaration, it can appear multiple times in the same TU (translation unit). But a structure _definition_ (like “`struct S { int x; void f(); };`”) defines the names and types of its members (needed to create variables and use them), so it must be unique in a given TU. But more than one TU may need the definition, so C++ allows duplicate definitions of the same struct in a program, but maximum one per TU, and all must be identical (and header inclusion permits that).

Comment: @gx_ Thanks for such detailed answer, now everything is clear for me.